# SAVE button to store data and retrieve later

Tags: android

I have looked around for the answer to this question, and I'm sure I have read it, but I dont understand it. Hope someone can help.

I want to save 'Name' 'Address' 'Support' (text, text, number respectively) to a file and then retrieve the info later for use (days, months, after phone reboot) in sending a text msg.

I found [openFileOutput()](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)
but I cant work out how to use it.

I am new to coding so don't really understand where the examples I have found belong.
Any help much appreciated.

EDIT----
What I am trying to do is: Create an app that will be a simple one button app for the end user.
Install it, add NAME, ADDRESS, and SUPPORT (mobile/cell number) to the "Settings" page.
Later, when you want help, the end user starts the app and hits the button.
The app retrieves the NAME, ADDRESS and sends them in a text to the SUPPORT number
Any more help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the values remain small, and you don't need them to be structured (like if you have user profiles or something), then Shared Preferences should be just fine. 100 ints only amounts to **400 bytes**, so even if the Shared Preferences were stored in memory, it's not a big deal.

click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for complete information about shared preferences

Comment: Thanks. But I really dont understand the help page. I am very new to this coding and although the concepts make sense, writing the actual code escapes me. When I say Im new, I mean a few days. If I had a button 'save' and 3 fields (text1, text2, int1) I wanted stored, what would the code look like? and where do I put it?

Comment: basically Preferences are typically name value pairs. They can be stored as `Shared Preferences` across various activities in an application

Comment: Man.. I'm bagging my head againts a wall. Could someone please explain all to me like im a 4 year old? I just am not getting it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with preferences, here is how you can do it.

1) Declare the preferences you want to store in an XML file, e.g `res/xml/preferences.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="pref_name"
        android:title="Name"
        android:defaultValue="" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="pref_address"
        android:title="Address"
        android:defaultValue="" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="pref_support"
        android:title="Support"
        android:defaultValue="" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

2) Extend `PreferenceActivity` to display a screen that will allow modification of these preferences:

```
public class TestActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);  
    }
}
```

3) Use these preferences to send an email for instance:

```
private void sendEmail(String emailAddress) {
    String name = getPreferences(0).getString("pref_name", "");
    String address = getPreferences(0).getString("pref_address", "");
    String support = getPreferences(0).getString("pref_support", "");

    String mailBody = "Name: " + name + "\nAddress: " + address + "\nSupport: " + support;

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/html");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddress);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mailBody);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));  
}
```

Comment: ok. Thanks heaps for the help. I THINK Im geting there. but the addPreferencesFromResouce(R.xml.preferences) line is giving me an error "xml cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: Did you create the file `res/xml/preferences.xml` ?

Comment: Yews I did. I think I have got files mixed up and whats in them mixed up. Im super new and dont really get the concepts of this programming. Ill try getting this sorted out with what you have given me here. Ill update/edit my original question to be more explanitory and maybe you could comment more. Thanks a lot for the help so far.